# Postgresql query to lookup emojis

Tags: sql, postgresql, unicode, emoji

I'm trying to lookup emojis on a table on postgresql.

Sometimes I've got this on my results:

```
# SELECT id, title FROM my_texts WHERE title ILIKE '[%';
  id   |                             title
-------+---------------------------------------------------------------

85981  | [<U+1F6AB>] forbidden sample text
```

I've tried to lookup which titles have this emoji using the following queries:

```
SELECT id, title FROM my_texts WHERE title ILIKE '%<U+1F6AB>';
SELECT id, title FROM my_texts WHERE title ILIKE '%\U+1F6AB%'
SELECT id, title FROM my_texts WHERE title ILIKE '%\U1F6AB%'
```

But none of these gave me the results that I want.

How to properly write this unicode character?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Postgres escape sequence might be what you're looking for: `WHERE title LIKE E'%\u1F6AB%'`.